# Google-Kick Start, ROUND-A, Allocation:- Test set skipped

Tags: python, python-3.x, optimization, greedy

I participated in Kick Start and attempted this question:

**Problem**

There are N houses for sale. The i-th house costs Ai dollars to buy. You have a budget of B dollars to spend.

What is the maximum number of houses you can buy?

**Input**

The first line of the input gives the number of test cases, T. T test cases follow. Each test case begins with a single line containing the two integers N and B. The second line contains N integers. The i-th integer is Ai, the cost of the i-th house.

**Output**

For each test case, output one line containing Case #x: y, where x is the test case number (starting from 1) and y is the maximum number of houses you can buy.

Full question:-  https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/000000000019ffc7/00000000001d3f56

AND this was my code

```
t = int(input())
if 1 <= t <= 100:
    for case in range(t):
        n, b = map(int, input().split())
        a = map(int, input().split())
        s, c = 0, 0
        for i in sorted(a):
            s += i
            if s <= b:
                c += 1
            else:
                print("Case #{0}: {1}".format(case+1, c))
                break
```

I kept on getting test set skipped, I just want to know what is wrong with my code?

Is there any possible test set where this solution won't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is one problem: if all houses can be bought, the code does not print anything.
You can fix that by simply moving the line `print("Case #{0}: {1}".format(case+1, c))` after of the inner loop.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this accepted one,

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std ;
int main() {
    int t ; cin >> t ;
    for(int cs = 1 ; cs <= t ; cs ++) {
        int n , b , cnt = 0 ; cin >> n >> b ;
        vector<int> a(n) ; for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i ++) cin >> a[i] ;
        sort(a.begin(), a.end()) ;
        for(int i = 0 ; i < n ; i ++) {
            if(a[i] > b) break ;
            else {
                b -= a[i] ;
                cnt ++ ;
            }
        }
        printf("Case #%d: %d\n", cs, cnt) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the tested solution -

```
tc = int(input())
for i in range(tc):
    n, budget = map(int, input().split())
    prices = list(map(int, input().split()))
    prices.sort()
    for j in range(n, 0, -1):
        if sum(prices[: j]) <= budget:
            print("Case #" + str(i+1) + ': ' + str(len(prices[: j])))
            break
    else: print("Case #" + str(i+1) + ': 0')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will fail when the budget is enough to buy all the houses.

The following is the accepted python code:

```
n = int(input())
if ((n>=1 and n<=100) or (n>=1 and n<=10**5)):
    z = []
    for i in range(0, n):
      x = [int(w) for w in input().split()]
      y = [int(j) for j in input().split()]
      y.sort()
      a = 0
      count = 0
      if sum(y) > x[1]:
        for k in range(0, len(y)):
          if (a == 0 and y[k]>x[1]):
            break
          elif (a <= x[1]):
            a+= y[k]
            count+=1
            if (a + y[k+1] > x[1]):
              break
        z.append(count)
      else:
        z.append(len(y))
    for i in range(0, n):
      print("Case #"+ str(i+1) +": " + str(z[i]))
```

Answer (score 0):

#Accepted code Python

```
t = int(input())
for j in range(t):
    n,b = map(int,input().split())
    n = list(map(int, input().split()))
    n.sort()
    s=0
    ans=[]
    for i in n:
        s = s+i
        if s<=b:
            ans.append(s)
    print("Case #{}: {}".format(j+1,len(ans)))
```